# After some time Call detect broadcast Receiver stop working in background

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-9.0-pie

Before i add code in my main activity for register broad cast receiver but on stack overflow some buddy write no need to register your receiver in main activity just register it from manifest only and after that i tried to run that app and it work fine in background but after some time it stop working.

register from manifest only
added these all permissions

In Manifest

```
Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS,
        Manifest.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS
ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS
MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION

       <receiver
        android:name="CallDetector"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action 
        android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" 
/>
            <action 
             android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" 
  />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Which version you use for testing app?

Comment: android pie (9)

Comment: On Android 8.0 or later, the receiver must be registered in code using the registerReceiver() method of the Activity class together with an appropriately configured IntentFilter object.Check documentation:https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Comment: yes . but i also tried that think... but no solution